# Convert factor to POSIXlt with propagating date in R

Tags: r, date, posixlt

I have a vector with time information and a date noted only once per day. I need to convert the vector into a usable format such as `POSIXlt`. The times are ordered, where all times (`%H:%M`) within a day belong to the last date noted before the date-less time.

```
t <- structure(c(6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L), 
    .Label = c("00:15", "00:25", "00:35", "00:45", "02:05", "20.01.2013; 0:05", 
    "20:48", "20:58", "21:08", "25.01.2013; 20:38"), class = "factor")
```

From multiple previous answers to questions about factor to date conversion (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21211406/5967807)), I know how to convert `t[c(1, 7)]`.

```
t1 <- strptime(as.character(t[c(1, 7)]), format = "%d.%m.%Y; %H:%M")
# t1
# [1] "2013-01-20 00:05:00 CET" "2013-01-25 20:38:00 CET"
```

However, how can I propagate the missing date for the remaining values so that they would convert correctly?

Comment: are these dates differ by a single day?

Comment: @akrun Mostly yes, but not always.

Comment: You really have two problems here: reshaping your data, and parsing datetime.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel True. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(zoo)  # For the na.locf function

df = data.frame(date=t)

# Put date and time in separate columns
df$time = gsub(".*; (.*)","\\1", df$date)
df$date = as.Date(df$date, format="%d.%m.%Y")

# Fill missing df$date values
df$date = na.locf(df$date)

# Convert to POSIXct
df$date = as.POSIXct(paste(df$date, df$time))
df = df[,1, drop=FALSE]

df

                  date
1  2013-01-20 00:05:00
2  2013-01-20 00:15:00
3  2013-01-20 00:25:00
4  2013-01-20 00:35:00
5  2013-01-20 00:45:00
6  2013-01-20 02:05:00
7  2013-01-25 20:38:00
8  2013-01-25 20:48:00
9  2013-01-25 20:58:00
10 2013-01-25 21:08:00
```

Comment: Nice. I would use `<-` instead of `=` but that is just me.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel. I guess I'm just too lazy to do all that extra typing :).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(t) %>%
     mutate(Date = as.Date(t, "%d.%m.%Y")) %>% 
     group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(Date))) %>%
     mutate(Date = Date[1L],
            DateTime = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, sub(".*;", "", t)))) %>% 
     ungroup() %>%
     select(DateTime)  
#           DateTime
#                <dttm>
#1  2013-01-20 00:05:00
#2  2013-01-20 00:15:00
#3  2013-01-20 00:25:00
#4  2013-01-20 00:35:00
#5  2013-01-20 00:45:00
#6  2013-01-20 02:05:00
#7  2013-01-25 20:38:00
#8  2013-01-25 20:48:00
#9  2013-01-25 20:58:00
#10 2013-01-25 21:08:00
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
i1 <- nchar(as.character(t))==5
v1 <- ifelse(i1, paste(sub(";.*", ";", t[!i1])[cumsum(!i1)], 
                     sub(".*;\\s+", "", t[i1])), as.character(t))

strptime(v1, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code added a date to each row. I have a variable number of rows belonging to a single date.

Comment: @nya Can you post a better example that reflects the problem.

Comment: Both answers work for me, but I'm accepting eipi10's, because it is easier for me to understand. Thank you for your alternative.